# Multiline string search output into one line

Tags: linux, string, awk, sed, grep

I have strings with a start and end token that I want to print out on a single line.
The cases are:

- a string could appear itself on one line - leave as is.

  - a string can occur on multiple lines - combine into one line.
  - the end token can occur across multiple lines - combine into one line.

For example I want to transform:

```
(start) AAAA 
(the end)

(start) BBBB (the end)
(start) CCCC (the 
end)
```

Into the output:

```
(start) AAAA (the end)
(start) BBBB (the end)
(start) CCCC (the end)
```

Currently I have this:

```
awk '/^\(start\)/{printf $0" ";next;}1' test.text

(start) AAAA  (the end)

(start) BBBB (the end) (start) CCCC (the  end)
```

Issues with this command are:

- the extra space after AAAA.
- BBBB and CCCC are on same line.
- The final end token has an extra space within.

What would be a good tool and solution for this?
I'd be happy for pointers in the right direction.

Comment: if this is really an html file, better to spend your time learing the options of an html pretty print utility like `tidy`. Good luck.

Comment: I assure you it is not HTML, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the line immediately, collect the line contents into a variable. When you get to the end marker, remove the excess spaces and print it.

```
awk '{ var = var " " $0 }
     var ~ /\(the +end\)/ { sub(/^ +/, "", var); gsub(/ +/, " ", var); print var; var="" }
    ' test.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following(this one will not take care of uneven spaces).

```
awk  'NF{printf("%s%s",$0,$0!~/\(the end\)$/?OFS:ORS)}'  Input_file
```

---

To get proper spaces try:

```
awk  'NF{$1=$1;printf("%s%s",$0,$0!~/\(the end\)$/?OFS:ORS)}' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
(start) AAAA (the end)
(start) BBBB (the end)
(start) CCCC (the end)
```

Comment: @user1330734, Could you please check above once and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/(start).*(the end)/b;/(start)/{:a;N;s/\n//;/(the end)/!ba}' file
```

If a line contains both the start and end conditions print it. Otherwise if a line contains the start condition, append the following line, remove the newline between them and test for the end condition. If the test for the end condition fails repeat otherwise print the current amended line.

In the original question the intended solution also removes empty lines, this can be added on i.e.

```
sed '/\S/!d;/(start).*(the end)/b;/(start)/{:a;N;s/\n//;/(the end)/!ba}' file
```

An alternative, slightly shorter solution:

```
sed '/\S/!d;/(start)/{:a;/(the end)/!{N;s/\n//;ba}}' file
```